# Anyway to backprob derivatives when derivatives of the custom loss function are calculated by myself

Tags: tensorflow

I have been using tensorflow to train deep NN acoustic models for speech recognition for a while. The loss function I use is Cross Entropy and the NN models performe very well. Now I want to change the loss function to a more complex one named MMI (Maximum Mutual Information) which is also a classical criterion used in speech recognition domain. I put one [paper](http://www.danielpovey.com/files/2013_interspeech_dnn.pdf) here which describes this loss function in case that you have interests.

When using this special loss function, the derivatives of the loss function w.r.t. the activations of output layer can be computed by some special algorithms defined in Hidden Markov Model scenario. It means that I can compute the derivatives of the loss function w.r.t. the activations of output layer by myself rather than just write out the loss function and   leave Tensorflow to calculate the derivatives automatically.

But based on my poor experiences, I don't know how to backprob the derivatives which I calculate by myself. Is there any way to do this without touching Tensorflow C++ source code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably yes if all the computation involved use existing tensorflow functions.

You just have to set up the chain of operations that compute the gradients from the current variables.

Then you just use `tf.assign_add()` to the variables with your gradients multiplied by minus the learning rate.

You are thus mimicking what happens in the background in TF usually.

**EDIT:** If calculations are made in numpy for instance for the gradients you can use.

```
#perform numpy calculations

a=f(output_npy,variables_npy)
grad_from_user=tf.placeholder(tf.float32, a.shape)
grad_update=tf.assign_add(variables_tf,-lr*grad_from_user)
#and then
sess.run(grad_update,feed_dict={grad_from_user:a,...})
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. The computation of derivatives of loss function w.r.t. activation of output layer is calculated outside of the Tensorflow, I tend to use a placeholder to receive these values. And you said I had to set up the chain of operations, does it mean that I have to calculate the unsolved derivatives by myself? What if the NN model are too complicated to easily figure out the chain operations, e.g. LSTM + CNN.

Comment: I do not understand the end of your comment, you can either use tensorflow backprop to do your work or do the work yourself. If you want to do a mix of the two you can use `tf.gradients()` which will give you the intermediates you want.

Comment: Based on the chain rule, i.e. dloss/dx = dloss/dy * dy/dx. I want to do backprop given the dloss/dy. The solution tf.gradients(y, x, grad_ys=<dloss/dy>) is exactly what I want. The same question can be found [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/4506). Thank you very much.